# How to call same function on all nested objects of same type?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, recursion, solid-principles

I have a class that contains an array of that same class. I want to be able to call a function and it be called for the parent, and all of its children. There are two ways that we have thought of doing it. I was wondering which is best, or if there is an even better solution.

1.) Have the methods within the class. In each method, call that same method for its children. Thus calling all the methods recursively down to the lowest child.
EX: someClass.callFunction()

2.) Be able to push the functions into the class from another class.This would then have an applyFunctions() method that calls all the functions pushed to that instance, and all of its children.
EX: someClass.pushFunction(callFunction())

Comment: Both approaches are viable, but it depends on the actual use case. Btw, instead of `pushFunction` you'd use the names `forEach`, `map` or `traverse` (depending on what exactly they are doing with the `callFunction`). But no, you wouldn't necessarily call this from *another* class - you can (and probably should) use the abstraction in the class's own methods

Comment: If you use the abstraction in the class's own methods, would this be breaking the Open/Closed principle since you have to edit this file every time you want to add new functionality? (Still trying to wrap my head around Open/Closed principle)

Comment: No, the Open/Closed principle is about interfaces, it doesn't mean you're not allowed to edit the file when you want to add functionality. As I said, it depends on the use case - if you're only implementing the tree as a plain data structure, putting business methods in it might break the single responsibility principle though.